# For some reason whenever I try to overload the operator=(const myArray& rhs) in c++ using double array my program just crash

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators

I'm trying to overload the operator=. I can compile it but whenever I run the program, if I've only A1=A2 is's ok but when I've A1=A2=A3 I get the next fail message:

"This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_array_new_length'
  what():  std::bad_array_new_length".

I'm attaching my .cpp file.
I'm new here so if there is anything else that you want me to send just let me know.

My .cpp file(including the copy constructor):

```
#include <cmath>
#include "Array.h"
myArray::myArray()
{
    size = 0;
    data = new double[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        data[i] = i;
    }
}
myArray::myArray(const myArray& orig) {
setSize(orig.getSize());
data = new double [getSize()];
for (int i = 0; i < getSize(); i++) {
    setData(i, orig.getData(i));
}
}
myArray myArray::operator=(const myArray& rhs)
{
    delete [] data;
setSize(rhs.getSize());
data = new double [getSize()];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    setData(i,rhs.getData(i));
}
}
```

Comment: Please add the listing of the errors you get.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Comment: And please, if possible, produce a shorter variant of the code.

Comment: `operator=` is supposed to change the current object __not__ create and new one and return it.

Comment: AFAICT your copy ctor is incorrect, you never initialize data before copying data into it.

Comment: please read about [mcve]. It will make it a lot easier to help you if you reduce your code to only that few lines that are needed to reproduce the problem (eg we dont need to see the `<<` overloads) also it helps if the code can be copied and compiled as is (eg there is no `main`)

Comment: Good reading on an approach to implementing `operator=`: [What is the copy-and-swap idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)

Comment: Your copy constructor doesn't allocate any memory. You probably intended `setSize` to do that, but forgot.